# Find complex $z$ that satisfies two complex inequations

Tags: complex-numbers, geometric-inequalities

I don't know if I am doing this right, can you help me with a hint?

> $$ {|z-1| \over |z| } < {1} ;    $$ and $$   {|z| \over |z-2| } < {1}$$ 
>   Find all the complex number $$z = x+iy$$ that satisfies these inequalities.

Solving for the first one:
$$
{|z-1| \over |z| } < {|z-1| } < {|z|} < (z+1)^2  < z^2  
$$
then
$$
z^2+2z+1 <z^2
$$
Solving further I got that
$$
z<-1/2
$$

For the second inequality I made a similar approach and I got that 
$ -1/2 < z < 1/2$

Can you help me with this? Thanks! :)

Comment: What does $|z|<(z+1)^2$ mean? Or $z<-1/2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$${|z-1| \over |z| } < {1}  \Leftrightarrow \\
|z-1| < |z| \Leftrightarrow \\
|z-1|^2 < |z|^2  \Leftrightarrow \\
(z-1)(\overline{z-1}) < z \overline{z}  \Leftrightarrow \\
z \bar{z} -z -\bar{z}+1 < z \overline{z}  \Leftrightarrow \\
1 < z+ \bar{z} $$

Now, if $z= x+iy$ then $z+\bar{z}=2x$.

The second inequality can be solved the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

For$z\ne 0$ the inequality becomes
$$
|z-1|<|z|
$$
this means that $z$ are represented by the points, in the Argand's plane, such that the distance from $A=(1,0)$ is less than the distance from $O=(0,0)$, that is the points on the right of the orthogonal bisector line of the segment $OA$, that is the line $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

You can use the same reasoning to solve the second inequality that is 
$$
|z|<|z-2|
$$
and find the points on the left of the  line $x=1$.

Now take the intersection of these two sets.

The figure is a further help ( blue $|z-1|<|z|$, red $|z|<|z-2|$)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong starting from
$$|z-1| < |z|$$
Instead it should be
$$(x-1)^2+y^2 < x^2+y^2$$
$$(x-1)^2+y^2 < x^2+y^2$$
$$x > \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

According to me the best way in such questions is to first understand geometrically what is bring asked. Here you have the following iequalities

> 1.) $|z-1| < |z-0| $ i.e points in plane closer to to 1 than 0, hence to the right of the line $x=1/2$
>
> 2.) $|z-1| < |z-2|$ interpret it like above. Satisfied by points to left of $x=3/2$
>
> 3.) $|z-0| < |z-2|$ Satisfied by points to the left of $x=1$.
>
> Points simultaneously satisfying all there are between $x=1/2$ and $x=1$

This is one of those problems where writing the solution took more time than getting it. I just drew the plane infront of me; marked the lines $x=0,1,2$, and marked the region above to get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\mid z-1\mid}{\mid z\mid}<1\Leftrightarrow \frac{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}<1\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{1+\frac{1-2x}{x^2+y^2}}<1\Leftrightarrow 1+\frac{1-2x}{x^2+y^2}<1\Leftrightarrow\frac{1-2x}{x^2+y^2}<0\Leftrightarrow 1-2x<0\Leftrightarrow 1<2x\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2}<x$$

$$\frac{\mid z\mid}{\mid z-2\mid}<1\Leftrightarrow\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}}<1\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}\Leftrightarrow x^2+y^2<x^2-4x+4+y^2\Leftrightarrow 4x<4\Leftrightarrow x<1$$

Putting these together yields $\frac{1}{2}<x<1$

Concerning your approach:
$\frac{\mid z-1\mid}{\mid z\mid}<\mid z-1\mid$ only holds iff $\mid z\mid>1$, which is not necessarily the case.

$\mid z-1\mid<\mid z\mid$ indeed holds, cause it is equivalent to the condition $\frac{\mid z-1\mid}{\mid z\mid}<1$

$\mid z\mid<(z+1)^2$ however is wrong. $(z+1)^2$ is the square of a complex number and thus it can also be a complex number itself. The complex numbers aren't totally ordered, so you can't put them in inequalities like you can do with real quantities like $\mid z\mid$ and that $(z+1)^2<z^2$ doesn't hold follows subsequently (this wouldn't even be true if $z$ were real).

Answer (score 0):

The two inequalities can be viewer as the intersection of the interiors of the  two hyperbolaes when we remove the points $A(0,0)$  and $B'(0,2)$

- $\mathbb E_1$ with centers $A(0,0), \, B(0,1)$
- and $\mathbb E_2$ with centers $A'(0,0), \, B'(0,2)$.

Obviously we say (draw a picture) that $\mathbb E_1 \subset \mathbb E_2$ which yields $\mathbb E_1\setminus {A(0,0)} \cap \mathbb E_2 \setminus {B'(0,2)}=\mathbb E_2\setminus {A(0,0)} $.

The remainder is trivial.